# What is meaning of canonical form of a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let A{1,2,3}, B1={1,2}, B2={2,3}. Find minset canonical form of B1 and B2. We know minsets generated by B1 & B2 are
A1 = B1 \cap B2^{c}
A2 = B1 \cap B2
A3 = B1^{c} \cap B2
A4 = B1^{c}\cap B2^{c}
then minset canonical or normal form of B1 is {1,2} and B2 is {2,3}. Thus I found that minset canonical form or maxset canonical form of a set or subset of a set is the collection of total number of elements of that set or subset of a set. Am I right? or there is any technical meaning of canonical form of a set. please expaline.

Comment: We need reference for nonstandard terms, such as "minset cononical form".  Or maybe this is terminology from computer science?

Comment: @GEdgar can you expaline its actual meaning?